# New file is getting created during FTP download

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I'm trying to download a file from server using FTP, the Java code works if the file is available in remote server but if the specific file is not available in the remote server a new file is getting created with same file name in local. How can I avoid this?

and I'm trying to check the properties such as last modified time, file created time etc.., of the specific file before download, I used MLST but getting type casting issues..!!

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class FTPDownloadFileDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "www.myserver.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "pass";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        // APPROACH #1: using retrieveFile(String, OutputStream)
        String remoteFile1 = "/test/video.mp4";
        File downloadFile1 = new File("D:/Downloads/video.mp4");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
        }

        outputStream2.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retrieveFile() method always writes a local file, whether or not the remote file exists. Instead, you can use [retrieveFileStream()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)) and check the reply code.

A [handy list of FTP reply codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) is available from Wikipedia. If 550 is received, it means the file does not exist.

Finally, you need to use [completePendingCommand()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand()) to complete the transaction and a [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) to write the file.

```
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile1);
int returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
if (inputStream == null || returnCode == 550) {
    System.out.println("Remote file does not exist");
} else {
    ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(buffer);
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1);
    outputStream.write(buffer);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: by using retrieveFileStream, the issue resolved. Any chance in getting file properties such as last modified date/created date can be retrieved without downloading the file to local?
I tried MLST, but I'm getting type casting issue...

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it is possible to get the creation date, only the last modification. ftpClient.getModificationTime(remoteFile1);

Comment: getModificationTime is not getting listed in my FTPClinet. Do we have any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your Outputstream automatically creates the File, even if the stream is empty.

I would recommend you check first if the file exists on the server and based on that you don't even create the outputStream:

```
boolean checkFileExists(String filePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile1);
    returnCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
    return inputStream == null || returnCode == 550;
}
```